# Any way to collapse marked text in Ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

In Codemirror, they have a method called markText() described here: http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_marker

One of the options for that method allows you to collapse the marked text and replace it with something else. So, for example I can find all instances of "foo" and replace them with say, an underscore, but the internal value for the text remains "foo". And when a user deletes the underscore, the entire token "foo" is deleted, under the hood.

I'd like to switch to Ace for a simple IDE-like interface I'm building but I pretty much need this feature. (Unfortunately Codemirror has other issues which are making me look elsewhere)

Is there any way to achieve this in Ace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no builtin way of doing this yet. But there are two ways to implement it. If you need to replace only a few instances you could use folds (see `session.addFold`), but if you need to have many replacements and replacements are going to be inside a token, you can change values of highlighting tokens in `session.bgTokenizer.lines`. In any case you should create feature request for this at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/new

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been playing with folding and was able to pretty much achieve what I needed. I'm going to look into bgTokenizer as well. Looks like I'm definitely moving to Ace :)

Comment: Glad that you are moving to Ace:), but just curious what was the issue with CodeMirror?

Comment: There's a bad bug with Android where the backspace button won't work, and there's no good workaround. Ace seems to work pretty well on every OS I've tested. Plus the codebase seems a bit more understandable, which is a plus for me incase I want to hack at it a bit.

Comment: Backspace not working is more of an issue with android keyboard than the editor see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2185

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I had read up on that, but for whatever reason Ace doesn't seem to exhibit that problem for me. I'm not sure how you guys avoid it but my Android phone and an emulator both are able to delete text, so that was a big deal. Thanks again for your input!